# Regular expression for date in selenium ide

Tags: selenium

I tried to create a regular expression for the below date format, where as I am unable to justify that, please help me out.

`04-Apr-2013 [10:58:13 GMT+05:30]`

This is what I came up with:

`\\d{2}-\\w{3}-d{4} [\\d{2}:d{2}:d{2} \\w{3}+\\d{2}:d{2}]`

Correct me where i have gone wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the square brackets as they have a special meaning in regular expressions and also some of your digit indicators doesn't have backslash prefix. I've tested the following regex and it worked for me:

```
regexp:\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3}\+\d{2}:\d{2}\]
```